# Connecting multiple TFT panels to Arduino Uno via SPI?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, multiplexer, tft

Is it possible to connect more than one TFT screen (like this one or similar: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1651) to an Arduino Uno?

I'm wanting to connect and control two color screens at once; note the touch functionality of the one linked above isn't really necessary, I just like the size and overall build. They have a version that works like a shield and sits on top of the Arduino, which would work I suppose if I bought another unit for the other screen. The breakout board version is more flexible but I don't know of a way to control two screens that require that many pins.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. All the SPI pins (MISO, MOSI and SCK) are all shared between the panels. You can even share the D/C and RST signals. The only signal that *needs* to be separate is the CS pin since this is the pin that identifies which panel is actively receiving commands and data at any one time. Also you don't need to connect up the MISO pin at all, since that is only connected to the SD card slot, not the TFT screen.

So each screen that you add just requires one more pin to be used. One screen uses 5 pins. Two screens use 6 pins. Three screens use 7 pins, etc.

And yes, for this the breakout version would be easier to work with than the shield version.

Comment: Similarly, would communicating in 8-bit mode be possible? If draw speed was a concern that is

Comment: Sure. The data lines are shared and wr and Rd are unique.

Comment: Actually for 8 bit parallel you can share RD and WR as well. It's the CS pin on there that is unique. I couldn't remember if there was a CS or not, and certainly on the 8-bit parallel TFT I just grabbed from my box there is a CS pin.